# Dispose of unused rows in a Data Table object upon refresh

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, refresh

This is something of a specific question but it seems like something that should be simple and I am thinking about it the wrong way.

I have a DataGridView, in a winform, that is bound to a datatable. I am constantly loading data in to this datatable to display (refreshing). I am doing this as follows (simplified):

```
public void FillTable( DataTable table, List<MyObject> parameters)
        {
            var lastParent = string.Empty;
            var index = 0;
            table.BeginLoadData( );
            foreach ( var parameter in parameters )
            {
                if ( parameter.ParentName != lastParent )
                {
                    lastParent = parameter.ParentName;
                    index = 0;
                }
                LoadRow( table, parameter, index++);
            }
            table.EndLoadData( );
        }

protected virtual void LoadRow( DataTable table, MyObject objectname, int index)
        {
            indexMap[objectname] = index;     
            table.LoadDataRow( new object[] { stuff }, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges );
        }

public void RefreshParameters( Dictionary<MyObject, string> incomingParameters )
        {
            foreach ( var value in incomingParameters.Keys )
            {
                LoadRow( MyDataTable, value, incomingParameters[value], indexMap[value], true );
            }
        }
```

This all works fine. When I initialize my datatable, I set its PrimaryKey to the first two columns of my table. This, and the indexMap, makes it so that when I load a row that is already there, it overwrites the old one, and when I load a row that isn't present it adds it. This is perfect.

My problem is that once I'm done with my Dictionary, I want to delete the rows that didn't get refreshed (old values), and make sure that my DataGridView stops displaying these. I can't find a good way to do this. Does anyone have any suggestions of a way to keep track of old values, load the data, and then remove old values from the data table and the corresponding DataGridView? I've tried things that I feel like should work but the DataGridView keeps displaying the old rows, even though the DataTable no longer has them.

Comment: '...but the DataGridView keeps displaying the old rows, even though the DataTable no longer has them.' - This is odd. How are you removing the rows from the datatable?